# MapSym not available in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, compiler-construction

Visual Studio 2005 was having `MapSym.exe` tool which could be used for generating symbol files from map files. I am unable to finding this tool in my Visual Studio 2012 installation. Is `MapSym` no longer supported/required?

Comment: I doubt this still exists - probably because it is consdered unneeded: if the map file gets generated, you might as well generate the pdb file at the same time

Comment: It was dropped at least as long ago as VS2008.  Hard to imagine it was present in VS2005, you might have copied it from an old VS6 install.

Comment: Thanks. Don't think I copied from VS6.